# GoogleSignInApi no me permite hacer login con una cuenta de google

Tags: android, google-signin

Me he encontrado con el siguiente problema, necesito acceder desde una aplicación a una cuenta de google que se seleccionará en tiempo de ejecución con el fin de acceder a las impresoras que dicha cuenta tenga añadidas en Google Cloud Print. En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026804/google-cloud-print-from-android-without-dialog) de SO en Inglés me he encontrado con una solución, utilizando FireBase podemos hacer SingIn desde una aplicación de forma nativa facilitando el id de usuario y clave secreta que nos proporcionan desde google console.

Aquí os dejo mi **MainActivity**:

```
public class CustomPrintActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private static final int REQUEST_SINGIN = 1;
private TextView txt;
public static final String TAG = "mysupertag";
public static final String URLBASE = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_print);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.gg_client_web_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.gg_client_web_id))
            .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint"))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    //Sign in when button is pressed
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });


    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "error connecting: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    Toast.makeText(this, "error CONN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SINGIN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d(TAG,result.toString());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
            Toast.makeText(this, "error: Google Sign In failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_SINGIN);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    txt.setText(user.getDisplayName() + "\n" + user.getEmail());//todo
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(CustomPrintActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    getAccess(acct.getServerAuthCode());
                }
            });
}

private void getPrinters(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "TOKEN: " + token);
    String url = URLBASE + "search";
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("GET", url)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "finished " + result.getHeaders().code() + ": " +
                            result.getResult());
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "nice");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error");
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void getAccess(String code) {
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    Ion.with(this)
        .load("POST", url)
        .setBodyParameter("client_id", getString(R.string.gg_client_web_id))
        .setBodyParameter("client_secret", getString(R.string.gg_client_web_secret))
        .setBodyParameter("code", code)
        .setBodyParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
        .asString()
        .withResponse()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result.getResult());
                if (e == null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.getResult());
                        getPrinters(json.getString("access_token"));
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

En mi `Manifest` he añadido los permisos de Internet y en `build.gradle` todas las dependencias necesarias.

Todo va bien hasta que selecciono desde el diálogo de Sign In de Google una cuenta, en ese momento, en el `onActivityResult`, `result.isSuccess` nunca es true, es decir, falla al hacer Sign in desde la cuenta que le facilito. He probado con varias distintas y nada.

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

**Actualización:**

Haciendo un poco de Debug en el onActivityResult, `result.getStatus()` me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
```

También me he dado cuenta gracias al usuario [JorgeSys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) que aparece este error en el LogCat:

```
E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE
```

Comment: habilitaste la API?

Comment: Desde Google Console, en credenciales, he creado un ID de cliente de OAuth 2.0. En FireBase he habilitado la aplicación pásandole el paquete de la misma ¿Necesitaría tener habilitado algo más?

Comment: Ya revisaste algún posible mensaje dentro del LogCat.

Comment: Nada a parte de los mensajes de debug que he definido previamente. Concretamente cuando pulso en el botón para hacer singin el resultado del intent de google que recibe en el onActivityResult contiene algo así: `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@xxxxxxxx` Es lo único que muestra el LogCat.

Comment: Disculpa, he encontrado el siguiente mensaje en color rojo en el LogCat: `E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras un largo día de dolores de cabeza he encontrado el problema, al parecer cuando creas un nuevo proyecto en FireBase, automáticamente te aparecerá también dicho proyecto en la google console, **mi fallo fue crear un nuevo proyecto en la consola de google y no utilizar el que aparece automáticamente**, ya que éste tarda un poco en aparecer.

Mencionar también que durante mi búsqueda de una solución me he cruzado con mucha gente que tenía errores similares a:

> E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please
>   check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE

por saltarse el paso de añadir la huella digital de certificado SHA en la configuración del proyecto de FireBase, [aquí](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) un enlace que explica como obtener el certificado .